# Compare user defined time and current time Java

Tags: java, date, time, compare

I am trying to compare user defined time in format HH:MM with current time in an infinite loop. When they are equal, some action should occur.

I have used following code:

```
//taking user input
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String time = jFormattedTextField1.getText();
userTime = sdf.parse(time);

//taking current time
Date timeNow = new Date();
while (true){
    if (timeNow.equals(userTime)){
    System.out.println("The time equals, task is done!");
    ChangingWindow window = new ChangingWindow(chosenColor);
```

When I print these 2 time points I recieve the following:

User time: Thu Jan 01 10:35:00 CET 1970

Current time: Tue Sep 29 10:33:21 CEST 2015

Current time is obviously ok but for user defined time he keeps returning epoch. If anybody has any suggestion I would be grateful!

Comment: If you like to post your fixed code, then do it as an answer. Editing the question is not the correct way.

Comment: I moved the new part of the question into a separate answer, because as I said [an answer doesn't belong to the question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288443/answer-embedded-in-question). I made this answer a "community wiki", so feel free to improve it, if you like. Btw the "accepted answer" checkmark should stay at Tobias's answer, because this was the answer that helped you to fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I will keep it in mind for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to compare time `HH:MM`,  I would suggest to use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html):

> "LocalTime is an immutable date-time object that represents a time,
>   often viewed as hour-minute-second."
>
> "This class does not store or represent a date or time-zone. Instead,
>   it is a description of the local time as seen on a wall clock."

```
LocalTime user = LocalTime.parse("12:55");
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

if (user.equals(now)) { ... }
```

Edit: in answer to your comment

`userTime` and `timeNow` aren't updated, then in each iteration you are comparing always the same values. The result will not change.  You need to update `timeNow` inside the `while`

Anyway I can't think about `while (true)` as a good idea. I don't know what you need to achieve but if you want to wait until the user time is reached, then I would determine the time remaining until then and sleep the process this amount of time. Something like:

```
long time = Duration.between(now, user).toMillils();
Thread.sleep(time);
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias, I still don't get good result but now it looks as it should. What do you think, is: while (true){if (timeNow.equals(userTime)){..do something...} a good idea to compare these 2 times? I mean, maybe I don't get final match because timeNow does not update itself always to current time but just to one point in time when the object is created? Please let me know if I didn't make myself clear. Thanks once again!

Comment: I've answered editing the post, it's too long for a comment

Comment: Correct Answer. You might consider using a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) with its own thread pool rather than a Timer, to free up the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set YEAR, MONTH, DAY it starts from 1/1/1970.

So basically you need to set YEAR, MONTH, DAY to the date you like.

In your code you are creating a new Date setting only hour and minutes and leaving the other values to default.

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)):

> This parsing operation uses the calendar to produce a Date. All of the calendar's date-time fields are cleared before parsing, and the calendar's default values of the date-time fields are used for any missing date-time information. 
>   **For example, the year value of the parsed Date is 1970 with GregorianCalendar if no year value is given from the parsing operation**.

Answer (score 0):

This is OPs(*) fixed code following Tobías's instructions:

```
//get user time and current time
String time = jFormattedTextField1.getText();
LocalTime userTime1 = LocalTime.parse(time);
LocalTime timeNow = LocalTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);

//calculate the diff in seconds
int timeDur = (int)Duration.between(timeNow, userTime1).getSeconds();
//start the timer object using this difference
Countdown countdown = new Countdown (timeDur);
```

(*) Extracted from the edited question, because it doesn't belong there ([see this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288443/answer-embedded-in-question))